# simulating reproduction and inheritance with dplyr and purrr functions

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to build an individual-based model in R that simulates a bird population over the course of its annual life cycle. So simulated individuals breed, migrate, die, etc., and this cycle continues over many years.

I have an initial population of birds that's represented as a data frame containing one individual per row and its attributes. Migration, mortality, etc. are written as piped functions that take in the data frame of individuals as an input. The population ('agents' data frame below) reproduces, migrates, individuals die, etc., and it looks like this:

```
agents <- agents %>%
    reproduce() %>%
    determine_migration_distance() %>%
    migrate() %>%
    mortality() %>%
    increment_age()
```

This will be placed inside a for-loop to have the cycle repeat itself each year for 50 years, and I'll add some more code to store the data of interest for each year.

The one function I'm having difficulty thinking about and creating is the one that simulates reproduction. First, females pair with a male. Second, females determine the number of offspring to produce (based off of the base rnorm function). This is still my 'agents' data frame, which looks like this at this step:

```
library(tidyverse)
agents <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L), 
    mate = c(101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 
    109L, 110L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), sex = c("female", 
    "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", 
    "female", "female", "female", "male", "male", "male", "male", 
    "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male"), ageClass = c("adult", 
    "adult", "adult", "adult", "adult", "adult", "adult", "adult", 
    "adult", "adult", "adult", "adult", "adult", "adult", "adult", 
    "adult", "adult", "adult", "adult", "adult"), migStrategy = c("migrant", 
    "resident", "resident", "migrant", "migrant", "resident", 
    "migrant", "resident", "migrant", "migrant", "resident", 
    "migrant", "resident", "migrant", "migrant", "migrant", "resident", 
    "resident", "resident", "resident"), numOffspring = c(4L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), mate = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), sex = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), ageClass = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), migStrategy = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), numOffspring = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), class = "col_spec")) 

> agents
# A tibble: 20 x 6
      id  mate sex    ageClass migStrategy numOffspring
   <int> <int> <chr>  <chr>    <chr>              <int>
 1     1   101 female adult    migrant                4
 2     2   102 female adult    resident               5
 3     3   103 female adult    resident               5
 4     4   104 female adult    migrant                5
 5     5   105 female adult    migrant                5
```

'id' is the individual's identifier, and 'mate' is the mate's identifier.

I'm then able to create a second data frame containing only offspring that I would like to eventually bind back to the agents data frame, but I need to have the offspring keep track of their parents and inherit information from them. Right now offspring take on their mother's id as a way of keeping track like so:

```
# function to determine sex
set_offspring_sex <- function(...) {
  randDraw <- runif(1, 0, 1)
  if (randDraw < 0.5) {
    val <- 'male'
  } else {
    val <- 'female'
  }
  return(val)
}

breedingFemales <- agents %>% 
  drop_na(numOffspring) # get rid of males

N <- as.vector(breedingFemales$numOffspring)

juv <- tibble(
  id = rep(seq(breedingFemales$id), times=N),
  mate = NA,
  sex = NA,
  ageClass = 'juvenile',
  migStrategy = NA,
  numOffspring = NA
)

juv <- juv %>%
  mutate(
    sex = pmap_chr(., set_offspring_sex)
  )
juv
```

However, I'd like to have female offspring inherit their mother's migration strategy ('migStrategy'), while male offspring inherit their father's strategy. Linking these data frames is where I'm having difficulty.

Is there a better way to structure my data frame before or during this step? And is there a dplyr or purrr way of having offspring inherit this information?

Comment: you could use `dplyr::left_join()` to temporarily join the offspring df to the parent one based on `id` in the parent df and `parent_id` in the offspring df. Then you could use `mutate` to change whatever fields you need and then `select` to get rid of the unneeded ones. Finally, make sure all the col names match and use `bind_rows` to append the offspring to the parents df. If you post a reproducible example I can explain better

Comment: @see24 I've added some code to produce the data frame of offspring

Comment: For future reference it makes things easier if you include the necessary `library()` calls in your code so it is clear what packages are needed

Answer (score 1):

Here is a worked example of what I said in my comment:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# join juv to agents table in order to get the parents ids
ag_juv <- breedingFemales %>% left_join(juv, by = "id", suffix = c("_ag", "_juv")) %>% 
  mutate(id_Mo = id, id_Fa = mate_ag) %>% 
  select(-contains("_ag"))

# join females to mothers to get mig strategy and give them a unique id
f_juv <- ag_juv %>% filter(sex_juv == "female") %>% 
  left_join(breedingFemales %>% select(id, migStrategy), by = c(id_Mo = "id")) %>% 
  mutate(migStrategy_juv = migStrategy,
         id = last(agents$id)+1:n()) %>% 
  select(-migStrategy) %>% 
  rename_at(vars(contains("_juv")), ~gsub("_juv", "", .))


# I will let you do the same for juv males


# append the juvs to the agents 

agents_gen2 <- agents %>% bind_rows(f_juv)
```